# more than one row in subquery percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT 
    status, date(time), 
    round((SELECT count(*) 
           FROM log 
           WHERE status NOT LIKE '200 OK'
           GROUP BY date(time) 
           ORDER BY date(time)) /
          (SELECT count(*) 
           FROM log 
           GROUP BY date(time) 
           ORDER BY date(time))) * 100 AS percent
FROM 
    log
GROUP BY 
    date(time), status, percent
ORDER BY 
    date(time);
```

I already written a code for it but, there is no response, I am using postgreSQL.
The final thing i want is to find THE ERROR PERCENTAGE STATUS(see the status colounm which have 200 Ok or not found) FOR EACH DAY.

FOR EG-- 2016/07/22 - 1.5% ERROR

P.S the database is really big with different status and dates, i want result date wise
In above code i am trying to find the (NOT-FOUND status/Total Status) for each day

Comment: In your expected result do you mean by "...trying to find the (NOT-FOUND status/Total Status) for each day" that the *Total Status* is for that particular day or you mean entire history of data recorded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with the existing query:

- the way you've solved it so far require the table **"log"** to be scanned 3 times causing huge performance cost
- in here >> `WHERE status NOT LIKE '200 OK'` << you are looking exact value match "200 OK" not pattern match, so you can drop using *LIKE* and use either *NOT()* like that >> `WHERE NOT status = '200 OK'` OR *<>* operator like that: `WHERE status <> '200 OK'`
- in order to divide higher number from lower, you need to cast your integer to numeric

For latter quick example:

```
SELECT 1 / 10;          -- results to 0
SELECT 1::numeric / 10; -- results to 0.10000000000000000000
```

**Solution**

To solve all mentioned and improve query and get expected result (if I did understand expected result correctly) then using WINDOW function this can be solved with query as simple as:

```
-- The query
SELECT  date(time),
        round(
            (count(1) FILTER (WHERE NOT status = '200 OK'))::numeric * 100 / count(1),
            1
        ) AS errors_rate
FROM    log
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;

-- Should return something like this:

 time       | errors_rate
------------+------------
 2016-07-05 |        1.2
 2016-07-06 |        1.3
 2016-07-07 |        1.5
...
```

Some helpful reads:

[PG Docs: Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#syntax-aggregates) 
[PG Docs: Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) 
["The FILTER clause in Postgres 9.4" by Anderson Dias](https://medium.com/little-programming-joys/the-filter-clause-in-postgres-9-4-3dd327d3c852)

Answer (score 0):

Compare the date inside the subqueries with the date outside (they should be the same), or you'll be counting for every date.